# Template + Typedef C++

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

if we have a line of code :

```
typedef bool (*cmp_func)(int i0, int i1);
```

How to change this to :

```
typedef bool (*cmp_func)(T i0, T i1);
```

where T - typename ?

Comment: What???????????

Comment: Typedefs cannot be templates. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I wil try to edit your post pal... IF, I thik I understood your q

Comment: Well if you don't care about deduction context you could wrap it into class template...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since C++11:

```
template <typename T>
using cmp_func = bool (*)(T, T);
```

Comment: Any downsides over using a typedef?

Comment: @Qix The only ones I'm aware of are that less people are familiar with it because it's newer, and that being a C++11 feature, it requires a compiler that supports C++11 or later.  Otherwise, a type alias is mechanically identical to a `typedef`, and an alias template (a templated type alias, basically) is mechanically identical to what a templated `typedef` would be if they existed.  See [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d3eb41a037efa4ca); for a given underlying type, aliases and `typedef`s for that type are identical.

Comment: (If you're not familiar with them, `static_assert` is a compile-time `assert`; it takes two parameters (a compile-time `bool` expression, and a string literal (optional as of C++17) that is emitted as an error message if the `bool` is `false`).  `std::is_same` is an SFINAE helper, that takes two types as template parameters; member `bool is_same::value` is `true` if both types are identical, or otherwise `false`.  `decltype` is a type deduction keyword, that evaluates (at compile time) to its argument's type; it's basically `sizeof`, but for type instead of size.)

Comment: I'm curious as to why we'd use `typdef` anymore, then (as of C++11). I knew we could use `using` for this kind of thing, but I don't even see the need of using a typedef anymore if they are functionally identical.

Comment: @Qix: `using` works with template, `using` have a more natural syntax. `typedef` is for C-compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

There is no template typedef, but you can have a typedef inside a template:

```
template <typename T> 
struct Foo {
    typedef bool (*cmp_func)(T i0, T i1);
};
int main() {
    Foo<int>::cmp_func f;
}
```

Or since C++11 you can do the same via [type aliasing](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias)

```
template <typename T>
using cmp_func = bool(*)(T,T);
```

Also note that even though C++11 has type aliasing, this comes with some restrictions (in particular they cannot be specialized) and sometimes it is necessary to combine both approaches.

Comment: [See type-aliasing](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias).